# Is possible to configure a Cisco 881 by DHCP?

Tags: cisco, dhcp

I'm wondering if is possible to configure a Cisco Router 881 from a file on a tftp instruct on a DHCP option. I know is possible to configure the wan port through DHCP by configuring "ip address dhcp" but what I search is there is a way to act as an Cable Modem CPE, dowload the configuration file from the DHCP and load it.

on the DHCP I've configure the following option as it will be for a CPE

```
filename "tftp://172.16.0.1/conf";
```

**warning** I'm not asking how to configure DHCP server on Cisco Router.

Comment: Which DHCP option for the file name?

Comment: I'm trying by adding the 'filename' line, option 66 tftp-server-name, option 67 bootfile-name on dhcpd.conf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there is a way to act as an Cable Modem CPE, download the configuration file from the DHCP [Option 67] and load it.

You are asking about [Autoinstall](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/configuration/guide/fcf002.html) in Cisco IOS:

- Router (with blank NVRAM) pulls an address from DHCP
- Router uses DHCP Options 3, 6, 66, 67, and 150 to reconfigure itself via TFTP

I also found a pretty good [blog post on autoinstall](http://enotepad.wordpress.com/2008/08/06/auto-install-over-frame-relay/)

If you're looking for a tool to perform Autoinstall, check out [freeztp](https://github.com/PackeTsar/freeztp); it's written in Python and uses a series of commands to set up configurable templates for IOS routers and switches.

Thank you for asking about this feature, I completely forgot it existed.